# get row in context menu command parameter mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datatable, datarow

I have set DataTable as ItemsSource for WPF DataGrid.
Now I have a context menu to delete any row. The command is handled in the view model which has DataTable object. But I need the row that raises the command. How can it be done?
What can be the command parameter?

Comment: Please post the XAML code of the datatable and command setup.   :-)

Comment: <DataGrid x:Name="grdData" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="750" ItemsSource="{Binding DtServiceHouse}"
                          
                 GridLinesVisibility="None" HeadersVisibility="Column" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

Comment: <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="mnuDeleteRow" Style="{StaticResource mnuDelete}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ServiceRevenueGrowth_P}" Header="Delete">
                        
                    </MenuItem>                    
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

Answer (score 0):

Since a ContextMenu is not part of the visual tree, we need to create a `Freezable` to act as a proxy to be able to contact the `DataGrid` to get the selected row(s).
Here is a quick and dirty proxy. You can change the property type to match your datacontext type, to make designtime binding validation work:

```
class DataContextProxy : Freezable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(DataContextProxy));


    //Change this type to match your ViewModel Type/Interface
    //Then IntelliSense will help with binding validation
    public object Data 
    {
        get { return GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new DataContextProxy();
    }
}
```

Then you set it on your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdData">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataContextProxy x:Key="Proxy"
                          Data="{Binding ElementName=grdData}"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding Data.SelectedItems, Source={StaticResource Proxy}"
                      Header="Delete"/>
       </ContextMenu>
   </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Now in your viewModel, in the DeleteCommand `CanExecute` and `Execute` handlers:

```
private bool DeleteCanExecute(object obj)
{
    var rows = obj as IList;
    if (rows == null)
        return false;
    if (rows.Count == 0)
        return false;
    return rows.OfType<DataRowView>().Any();
}
private void DeleteExecute(object obj)
{
    var rows = obj as IList;
    if (rows != null)
        foreach (DataRowView rowView in rows)
        {
            var row = rowView.Row;
            //Handle deletion
        }
}
```